# Unsuccessful installation of Oracle java package

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to add Oracle's PPA in my Ubuntu 16.04 with the following command:
   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
But it shows error with the following messages:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~webupd8team/ubuntu/java'.
ERROR: '~webupd8team' user or team does not exist.
```

I referred [Installation of JDK in Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)

How can i resolve it?

Comment: You miscopied the command correctly from the page you linked to!

Answer (score 0):

Try again. I just tried running the following command with Ubuntu and it worked: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`.

I suppose you have had a typo in your command or a temporary failure of the server.